# Radio Button with JSF Pass-Through?

Tags: html, responsive-design, radio-button, jsf-2.2

We work with externally provided HTML5 sources (responsive design). Our challenge is to add the logic with Java, while preserving the exact HTML rendering.

I found [JSF Pass-Through](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-facelets009.htm) to be helpful in this context.

But I cannot get **radio buttons** working. I am not sure how to do the wiring with the attribute in the managed bean ("stringAttribute" in the example). In the POST data I see the value for the selected radio button coming through, but JSF does not set it in the managed bean.

Does anybody see what is wrong with my attempt here?

Or is this simply not supported? (type="radio" does not appear in "Table 8-4 How Facelets Renders HTML5 Elements" in the Oracle doc).

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf" 
      xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

<h:form>
    <input jsf:value="#{myBean.stringAttribute}" pt:value="firstChoice" pt:name="the-radio-group" type="radio"/>
    <input jsf:value="#{myBean.stringAttribute}" pt:value="secondChoice" pt:name="the-radio-group" type="radio"/>

    <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit" action="#{myBean.submit}"/>
</h:form>
```

Or how would you approach this? Remember that I have quite complex HTML which must be rendered exactly using JSF. To give you an idea, here is the HTML I am trying to produce:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-12 mod-formelem">
        <input data-enslaved-group="radio" data-enslaved-master="radio-1" id="___radio204_01___" name="___radio204___" type="radio"/>
        <label class="mod-formelem--icon mod-icon icon-checkbox_checkmark_16" for="___radio204_01___"/>
        <label class="mod-formelem--text" for="___radio204_01___">Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 mod-formelem">
        <input data-enslaved-group="radio" data-enslaved-master="radio-2" id="___radio204_02___" name="___radio204___" type="radio"/>
        <label class="mod-formelem--icon mod-icon icon-checkbox_checkmark_16" for="___radio204_02___"/>
        <label class="mod-formelem--text" for="___radio204_02___">Option 2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you seen how the html was generated in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

This question is two years old without being answered, but the problem still persists, so it may be worth the pain to answer it so other developers facing the same problem benefit from it.

It seems to be impossible to implement radio buttons using JSF pass through variables. However, CSS frameworks like Bootstrap require you to use a different HTML code than JSF generates. In this case, you can simulate the radio button as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415814/how-to-transform-a-radio-input-form-to-radio-input-bootsfaces-form). The example, in particular, uses Bootstrap and BootsFaces, but the idea can be generalized for other frameworks as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think is not impossible. You can try this solution:

[Custom layout with h:selectOneRadio in JSF 2.2](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2015/10/custom-layout-with-hselectoneradio-in.html)

Comment: Please add key point of your solution to your answer, instead of just a link.